# Как сделать, чтобы бот отправил предложение о сделке от первого ко второму пользователю бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу гарант бота в телеграм на библиотеке Aiogram на v2 (но если знаете как сделать на 3 тоже будет очень полезно). И чтобы создать сделку, один пользователь должен ввести юзернейм второго человека для создания сделки и отправить боту, после этого бот должен отправить запрос о предложении. И второй человек должен принять или отклонить это предложение.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, не нашел вообще никаких тем про гарант ботов в интернете. Буду очень рад если расскажете механизм действия, а если поможете с кодом, буду вам признательнее вдвойне.

Comment: Что вы будете делать, если у пользователя нет юзернейма? А если он поменяется в процессе проведения сделки? Что конкретно у вас не получается? А то вы описали некий абстрактный кусок. По описанному нечто такое: пишем данные юзеров в бд, уогда кто-то пишет - дергаем user_id, и отправлем ботом сообщение на этот id

Comment: @CausonQ Доброе утро, хорошо, тогда id пользователя. У меня не получается понять как это реализовать, понимаю, что через бд, но как это сделать технически, у меня с кодом проблемы. Хочу сделать, чтобы сделка создавалась от одного и отправлялась в чат с ботом другому юзеру, который уже есть в бд. Причем нужный id должен вписать первый юзер бота.

Comment: Все таки, нужно начинать с того, каким образом продавец и покупатель будут узнавать друг о друге? Если на стороннем ресурсе, то может лучше использовать ссылку с параметром, что бы сразу определять участников? Если в самом боте, id участников уже должны быть известны. Кроме того, id не так просто узнать, в сравнении с username

Comment: @CausonQ Они будут договариваться о сделке вне бота, дальше у меня в боте уже реализована система, которая показывает их id и юзернейм, продавец просто поделится своим id также вне бота, после этого нужно как то отправить сделку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за предложенные варианты, но я нашел то, что искал. Чтобы отправить запрос о сделке другому юзеру (оба они должны были запустить бот, чтобы у бота был доступ к чату каждого) нужно было добавить всего лишь этот небольшой кусочек кода, надеюсь я кому то помог кроме себя!

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='offer')
async def offer(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer('Введи нужное id')

@dp.message_handler()
async def send_offer(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user_id = message.text
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = user_id, text='Новая сделка')
    except:
        await message.answer(text='Такого пользователя нет')
```

*Я обрабатываю сообщение через кол дату, а не команду.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Deep-link](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#bot-links)
Выдавайте продавцу индивидуальную ссылку вида `t.me/<bot_username>?start=<parameter>`, где `<parameter>` - это некое уникальное значение, к примеру `user_id`.

Примерная схема: продавец дает ссылку покупателю. Покупатель, при переходе по ссылке жмет кнопку старт, бот же сразу принимает этот переданный параметр, достает из БД данные продавца. И все, у вас ест все необходимые данные, и соединить участников уже не представляет проблемы

Comment: спасибо, не думал, что есть такой вариант, но хотелось бы как то реализовать это все внутри бота, чтобы не было действий извне, а то потом придется решать проблемы с обманом людей.

Comment: @Giga_Bird ну так вы ж говорите, что покупатели будут из вне. Если все в пределах бота, то у вас уже есть все необходимые данные. Весь вопрос в том, каким образом покупатель и продавец будут находить друг друга. Это вы в вопросе не указали

Comment: покупатель и продавец находят друг друга в группе телеграм, дальше им нужно провести сделку, они идут в бота, запускают, далее у каждого из них есть id в "личном кабинете" бота, кто то делится id для создания сделки, дальше кто либо пишет команду создать сделку, бот ждет id, дальше если есть такой id в бд то бот присылает второму участнику бота предложение о сделке. Думаю понятно объяснил.